# R - Function that dichotomizes certain columns of a data frame based on different thresholds

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I am trying to create a function that dichotomizes certain defined columns of a data frame based on different values depending on the column.

For example, in the following data frame with conditions A, B, C and D:

```
A <- c(0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2)
B <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
C <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
D <- c(0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 0, 3, 0)
Data <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
```

I would like the function to dichotomize the conditions that I select [e.g. A, B, D] and dichotomize them based on thresholds that I assign [e.g. 2 for A, 1 for B, 3 for D].

I would like the dichotomized columns to be added to the data frame with different names [e.g. A_dich, B_dich, D_dich].

The final data frame should look like this (you will notice B is already dichotomized, which is fine, it should just be treated equally and added):

```
   A B C D A_dicho B_dicho D_dicho
1  0 0 0 0       0       0       0
2  2 1 0 0       1       1       0
3  1 1 0 3       0       1       1
4  0 1 1 1       0       1       0
5  2 0 1 2       1       0       0
6  1 0 1 1       0       0       0
7  0 0 1 4       0       0       1
8  0 1 1 0       0       1       0
9  1 1 1 3       0       1       1
10 2 0 1 0       1       0       0
```

Could someone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a little threshold vector specifying the values, then `Map` it to the columns:

```
thresh <- c("A"=2, "B"=1, "D"=3)
Data[paste(names(thresh), "dicho", sep="_")] <- Map(
  \(d,th) as.integer(d >= th), Data[names(thresh)], thresh
)
Data
##   A B C D A_dicho B_dicho D_dicho
##1  0 0 0 0       0       0       0
##2  2 1 0 0       1       1       0
##3  1 1 0 3       0       1       1
##4  0 1 1 1       0       1       0
##5  2 0 1 2       1       0       0
##6  1 0 1 1       0       0       0
##7  0 0 1 4       0       0       1
##8  0 1 1 0       0       1       0
##9  1 1 1 3       0       1       1
##10 2 0 1 0       1       0       0
```

Comment: That works perfectly, many thanks. How would you proceed if the dichotomization was not to be carried out based on thresholds but based on correspondence. Let's say I wanted A=2, B=1 and D=2 or D=4 to be 1 and all other values to be 0. D_dicho should then be `0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0`. Maybe with a vector like `corresp <- c("A"=2, "B"=1, "D"=c(2, 4))`?

Comment: @CNiessen - Change the function to compare with %in% instead and make `thresh` a named list of four sets of values and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that works! However, if I make `thresh` a named list of four values (e.g. `c("A"=2, "B"=1, "D"=2, "D"=4)`), the function will also return four dicho columns: `A_dicho`, `B_dicho`, `D_dicho` and `D_dicho.1`. What would I need to do to only get one column `D_dicho` that takes into consideration both D=2 and D=4 and returns `0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0`?

Comment: @CNiessen - use a list, not a vector: `list("d"=c(2,4))`